# bad_alloc exception when I try to split string msvc c++ 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to split a string which is given from the `getline(cin, str)` in a function which is not `main()`.

I have copied the string split code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string) but it throws a `bad_alloc` error from `xmemory` when I try to execute it.

I have used the first answer and also tried to use `boost::algorithm::string::split` but this method also throws the same exception that I encountered.

I think this exception arises from `vector<string>` memory allocation, but I have no idea how to fix this exception.

I am using visual studio 2017 and windows 10 build 1607 x64. The code was tested on two machines and throws the exception at the same line with `ntdll.dll` associated with it.

Here is my code:

```
// code from the link
template<typename Out>
void split(const std::string &s, char delim, Out result) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        *(result++) = item;
    }
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, std::back_inserter(elems));
    return elems;
}

// my code
void readScript(string* command, int* col, int* row, MineSweeper* m)
{

    cout << "Input command separated by space: ";
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    vector<string> tokens;
    tokens = split(str, ' ');
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's most likely that the problem is caused by code that is not posted. I tried the posted code and it works as intended.

Comment: Actually, I have tried to compile the whole code with g++ 7.1.0, and it works... Should I think this error come from the compiler?

Comment: It's hard telling what could be wrong with a [mcve].

Comment: I fixed it somehow by looking over all the code but still couldn't figure what cause the problem but thanks though.